# compare two matrices with criteria in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices

```
A
2 1 0
0 1 6
1 0 0
B 
1 1 3
4 2 8
2 0 1
```

I want to find out the elements comparing A and B satisfying the following criteria:

```
if A[i,j] =0 and B[i,j]>0
```

So my result matrix should be

```
C
0 0 3
4 0 0
0 0 1
```

What is a proper way to do this except for a `for loop`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular logical and arithmetic operators act element wise on matrices in R. Only the `%*%` and kronecker operators do matrix multiplication.  Furthermore you can index matrixes using the "["  and "[<-" functions:

```
> C <- B
> C[!( A==0 & B >0) ] <- 0
> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    3
[2,]    4    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't sure which element you wanted if this was true so I assumed the sum:

```
A <- matrix(c(2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 0, 0),3,3,byrow=TRUE)
B  <- matrix(c(1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 8, 2, 0, 1),3,3,byrow=TRUE)

C <- ifelse(A==0 & B>0, A+B, 0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    3
[2,]    4    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

But clearer might be using `which`:

```
which(A==0 & B>0, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   1   3
[3,]   3   3
```

## edit:

Note that the correct way of indexing a matrix is `A[i,j]` instead of `A[i][j]`.

Comment: In the first solution the `A+B` doesn't seem necessary. Should work with just `B`.

Comment: Yes. I just made a random guess to what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple comparison operators on the matrices.

Recreate the data, using:

```
A <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
2 1 0
0 1 6
1 0 0"))

B <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
1 1 3
4 2 8
2 0 1"))
```

Perform the comparison:

```
A==0 & B>0
        V1    V2    V3
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And then use `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(A==0 & B>0, B, 0)
     V1 V2 V3
[1,]  0  0  3
[2,]  4  0  0
[3,]  0  0  1
```